# A small help in understanding basic SVM

Tags: machine-learning, svm, vector-fields

I am on the course of learning SVM. So, I am having a doubt. Suppose in the case of 2D, a point needs to be classified. So, let say I am having a point x(2,3). So according to the equation wx+b >= 1 for being positive class. So, When I am taking w.x(2,3) + b , what is really happening here.

How this dot product between w and point , say x(2,3) here make changes geometrically.

How this change modifies, when b is added to the dot product.

My question may be dump, but I think geometric understanding will be too good to visualize. I need to know, how the dot product helps the hyperplane to distinguish positive and negative classes, geometrically when wx+b is greater than and less than one respectively. Thanks .

Comment: Define a hyperplane (2D line) by drawing a norm vector. Any direction will be fine. For simplicity, draw the hyperplane through the origin. The draw a vector with its tail in (0,0) and other end (2,3). Draw the projection of your vector on the norm vector and notice it's sign - positive or negative.

Comment: Check out this great tutorial by C. Burges (A Tutorial on Support Vector Machines for Pattern Recognition, http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/67119/svmtutorial.pdf). It explains SVMs in the terms you are looking for in great detail.

Comment: @juampa - Thanks alot. Thanks to you all guys for your immediate responses.